# How to customize the quick settings drop-down menu in android 4.2?

Tags: settings, 4.2-jelly-bean, customization, quick-settings

As of title, is there any way to customize the quick settings grid available in Android 4.2 ? This feature has potential, but in most cases it does not take advantage of the screen size.

[image: The quick settings panel]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently I can only find customization options through mods or other updates to the ROM. For example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1999125

It would really be great if stock Android 4.2 would provide functionality to add tiles, re-order tiles or change the function of long/short taps on tiles. This issue has some of those feature enhancement requests: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40285

Comment: Basically meaning no you can not customize it through stock Android itself.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Android 4.1.2 especially in Samsung Galaxy Note 2. `Settings-> Display-> Notification Panel`. Then drag and adjust required combinations.

Comment: I believe this is a Samsung only feature, it's not available on stock Android.

Answer (score 1):

If there's still anyone interested in getting the answer, the best I know is by using [Notification Toggle by j4velin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle). It can be customized to display toggles(Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc) or to launch apps.

Comment: Looks like a useful app! But it also looks like it just adds a notification with its own buttons rather than customizing the system quick settings menu. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

My stock Android 4.2 and 4.4 devices doesn't allow Quick Settings customization. To customize it, I had to settle with [Gravitybox [JB]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox) which needs [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and root access.

My initial stock Quick Settings were more or less similar to the one you posted. After my favorite tweaks it looks like (see an app's icon too):

[image: IMG - Tweaks]

The usage is simple. You install, activate, launch this app → **Statusbar tweaks → QuickSettings management** and do the tweaks as per your needs.

And don't worry regarding it's description related to Mediatek devices only. It works on Qualcomm ones as well.