# How do I customize sleep timeout button presets in quick settings panel?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, standby

Here is an image to make clear what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you see, this button have 3 positions. I figured out what these are corresponding to *Sleep after* 15 sec, 30 sec and 1 min, respectively.

Problem is, I use my 4.2.2 tablet for reading pages of text (like e-books or manuals), and my optimal timeout for everyday reading is 2 min. So neither preset suits my needs and it renders this button rather useless.

Moreover, this button gives me hell when I accidentally touch it, because it resets to the one of preset timeouts and I have to visit Settings and restore my preference.

How I customize these preset timeouts?
Alternatively, I'd like to know a way to remove offending button.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember there is a Timeout shortcut on quick setting, and it seems the quick setting layout is different from mine. What tablet are you using?

Comment: Well, haven't seen that though over my tab too ! I don't think that shortcut can be synchronised ! Anyway it would be a great help if you can let us know about which tablet you are using ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the quick settings drop-down menu in android 4.2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/how-to-customize-the-quick-settings-drop-down-menu-in-android-4-2)