# Remove Screen Record and Screen Shot from Quick Settings

Tags: screenshots, screencast

On a Chinese Tablet running on Kitkat 4.4.2 there's 2 options "Screen Shot" and "Screen Record" on the Quick Settings Swipe Down. I'm struggling to find a way so I can disable or remove those functions.

I've attached an image to further explain what I'm looking for.
[image]

Comment: If you can root the device and successfully install Xposed Framework, then GravityBox[KK] can help you out precisely. See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/114019/96277

Comment: @Firelord thank you for the update, I'll give it a try. Does that work the same for Settings if for example I wanna disable or hide certain packages e.g. Backup & Restore, Developer Options, Accounts Section?

Comment: That feature is something I've not found in that app.

Comment: Great to hear that i'm working on it. Thanks I'll update you if any :)

Comment: Excuse again can I add a shortcut for LockScreen package to directly access it and set either PIN, Password or Pattern?

Comment: Oh no. I recognizes this device. Does it say 'alldaymall' on the back?

Comment: GravityBox allows adding app shortcuts to Quick Settings Menu.